# Why are higher doses of atropine required to produce central effects?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, blood-circulation, central-nervous-system

Reason given in my book is restricted entry into the brain..is it something to do with the chemisty?

Comment: Can you give more context as to how the book is referring to atropine being administered? If you are talking about IV administration this is wrong. Could you provide a citation and quote from the book?